# Rearrange the negative elements of the array so that they are in non-descending order

Tags: ruby

Rearrange the negative elements of the array so that they are in non-descending order. Leave the remaining elements in their places.
It will show like that: [-1, 1, -3, 6, -5, -9] -> [-9, 1, -5, 6, -3, -1]
How can I do this without using additional arrays?

Comment: This looks like a kata and we will not be solving this for you. Please attempt your own solution first.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do that. Here is one.

```
arr = [-1, 1, -3, 6, -5, -9]

negs = arr.select { |n| n < 0 }.sort
  #=> [-9, -5, -3, -1]
arr.map { |n| n >= 0 ? n : negs.shift }
  #=> [-9, 1, -5, 6, -3, -1]
```